# Is there any method similar to in_groups_of in rails but for hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to split this hash in groups of size number, let's just say 2 items per group

```
hash = {'mail1@email.com': {name: 'name 1'},
        'mail2@email.com': {name: 'name 2'},
        'mail3@email.com': {name: 'name 3'},
        'mail4@email.com': {name: 'name 4'},
        'mail5@email.com': {name: 'name 5'}
       }
```

wanted result should be:

```
hash1 = {'mail1@email.com': {name: 'name 1'},
        'mail2@email.com': {name: 'name 2'}}

hash2 = {'mail3@email.com': {name: 'name 3'},
        'mail4@email.com': {name: 'name 4'}}

hash3 = {'mail5@email.com': {name: 'name 5'}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), after that map each element as a hash with [`Array#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-to_h):

```
hash1, hash2, hash3 = hash.each_slice(2).map(&:to_h)
p hash1 # {:"mail1@email.com"=>{:name=>"name 1"}, :"mail2@email.com"=>{:name=>"name 2"}}
p hash2 # {:"mail3@email.com"=>{:name=>"name 3"}, :"mail4@email.com"=>{:name=>"name 4"}}
p hash3 # {:"mail5@email.com"=>{:name=>"name 5"}}
```